# can't get custom field added to register form to save

Tags: magento-1.7

Ive added two new fields to magento customer register form on magento 1.7.0.2 using [this manual](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/customers_and_accounts/registration_fields).

Fields seems to be added fine to the DB and also visible under the admin but just not being saved. Running a var dump on the customer object ($this->getCustomer()) doesn't show the new attributes I added.

Can anyone give me a lead here because I'm running in circles

Comment: I'm having this problem too and really need a solution for this! Too bad Magento doesn't have a feature for this just yet, I'd say this is a key feature that many webshops would need. (Mainly adding this comment to make this question active again..hopefully)

Answer (score 3):

Hi i found a solution to this problem please add your `db fields collection` in following file

```
app\code\core\Mage\Review\Model\Resource\Review\collection.php on line 104
```

**change**

```
 array('detail_id', 'title', 'detail', 'nickname', 'customer_id'));
```

**to**

```
 array('detail_id', 'title', 'detail', 'nickname','pros','cons','city','age', 'customer_id'));
```